# jQuery send multiple value in another input

Tags: jquery, input, send

I have created a loop for displaying a shop's identity card.

The card's content contains information about the shop (phone, address...). the card has a button for selecting the shop, and I want send the multiple values to another `input`.

```
<li>

<span onclick="doSomething()" value="3">Select this Shop</span>
<input class="info-1" type="hidden" value="footlocker">
<input class="info-2" type="hidden" value="13 street 1000">
<input class="info-3" type="hidden" value="new york city">
<input class="info-4" type="hidden" value="00 22 55 66 33">
<input class="info-5" type="hidden" value="ID shop 6">

</li>


<li>
<span onclick="doSomething()" value="5">Select this Shop</span><br/>
<input class="info-1" type="hidden" value="Mc Donald">
<input class="info-2" type="hidden" value="256 avenue clint">
<input class="info-3" type="hidden" value="San Diego">
<input class="info-4" type="hidden" value="31 64 21 54 12">
<input class="info-5" type="hidden" value="ID shop 34">
</li>
...
```

The information is send in the input here

```
<input id="info-1" value="">
<input id="info-2" value="">
<input id="info-3" value="">
<input id="info-4" value="">
<input id="info-5" value="">
```

My jQuery

```
function doSomething(){


    var text= $('.info-1').attr('value');
    $( "#info-1" ).val(text);

    var text =  $('.info-2').attr('value');
    $( "#info-1" ).val(text);

    var text =  $('.info-3').attr('value');
    $( "#info-1" ).val(text);

    var text =  $('.info-4').attr('value');
    $( "#info-1" ).val(text);

    var text =  $('.info-5').attr('value');
    $( "#info-1" ).val(text);
}
```

This code doesn't work and if does work it sends only the value of the first shop :(.

Thanks for your help

https://jsfiddle.net/zjo1y4vv/3/

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Try to explain your question better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zjo1y4vv/7/)

Html should look like this

```
<li>
  <span onclick="doSomething(this)" value="3">Select this Shop</span>
  <input class="info-1" type="hidden" value="footlocker">
  <input class="info-2" type="hidden" value="13 street 1000">
  <input class="info-3" type="hidden" value="new york city">
  <input class="info-4" type="hidden" value="00 22 55 66 33">
  <input class="info-5" type="hidden" value="ID shop 6">
</li>
<li>
  <span onclick="doSomething(this)" value="5">Select this Shop</span>
  <br/>
  <input class="info-1" type="hidden" value="Mc Donald">
  <input class="info-2" type="hidden" value="256 avenue clint">
  <input class="info-3" type="hidden" value="San Diego">
  <input class="info-4" type="hidden" value="31 64 21 54 12">
  <input class="info-5" type="hidden" value="ID shop 34">
</li>
<br/> 
My container where is send the value :
<input id="info-1" value="">
<input id="info-2" value="">
<input id="info-3" value="">
<input id="info-4" value="">
<input id="info-5" value="">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  function doSomething(el) {
    var infomag = $(el).siblings('.info-1').val();
    $("#info-1").val(infomag);

    var text2 = $(el).siblings('.info-2').val();
    $("#info-2").val(text2);

    var text3 = $(el).siblings('.info-3').val();
    $("#info-3").val(text3);

    var text4 = $(el).siblings('.info-4').val();
    $("#info-4").val(text4);

    var text5 = $(el).siblings('.info-5').val();
    $("#info-5").val(text5);
  }
```

There are a bunch of things wrong with your fiddle.

1. `doSomething(this)` - add a parameter `this` in your html
2. you have the id `info-4` twice.
3. Use `.siblings` to find the text

Comment: Thankk you so much ! i try this and i come say if it's ok  :)

Comment: @MickaelFlaszenski - glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this : (You can factorize the code if you add others infos)

```js
$(".span").click(function(e){

    var infomag = $(this).siblings('.info-1').attr('value');
    $("#info-1").val(infomag);
    
    var text =  $(this).siblings('.info-2').attr('value');
    $("#info-2").val(text);
    
    text =  $(this).siblings('.info-3').attr('value');
    $("#info-3").val(text);
    
    text =  $(this).siblings('.info-4').attr('value');
    $("#info-4").val(text);
    
    text =  $(this).siblings('.info-5').attr('value');
    $("#info-5").val(text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>

<span class="span" value="3">Select this Shop</span>
<input class="info-1" type="hidden" value="footlocker">
<input class="info-2" type="hidden" value="13 street 1000">
<input class="info-3" type="hidden" value="new york city">
<input class="info-4" type="hidden" value="00 22 55 66 33">
<input class="info-5" type="hidden" value="ID shop 6">

</li>


<li>
<span class="span"  value="5">Select this Shop</span><br/>
<input class="info-1" type="hidden" value="Mc Donald">
<input class="info-2" type="hidden" value="256 avenue clint">
<input class="info-3" type="hidden" value="San Diego">
<input class="info-4" type="hidden" value="31 64 21 54 12">
<input class="info-5" type="hidden" value="ID shop 34">

<br/>
My container where is send the value :<br/>

<input id="info-1" value=""><br/>
<input id="info-2" value=""><br/>
<input id="info-3" value=""><br/>
<input id="info-4" value=""><br/>
<input id="info-5" value=""><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hints and fixes:

1. `$('.info-1')` will select multiple elements. Try to get the only one element in the right context, e.g. with `$(this).next('.info-1')` or `$(this).parent().find('.info-1')`
2. Within the `doSomething()` function you only set the value for `#info-1`, not for `#info-2` and so on.
3. To get the value of an input use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`